# Shouldn't an object orbit and not spin when it first translated and then rotated?

Tags: opengl, transformation-matrix

I understand that the transform order matters, but I don't understand why the object in [this](https://youtu.be/HHmca-Vom1M) tutorial on minute [7:00](https://youtu.be/HHmca-Vom1M?t=464) spins and not orbits.

Line [156](https://youtu.be/HHmca-Vom1M?t=456) applies rotation and then translation on Model matrix `MathHelper::matrixMul4x4(M, transMatrix, rotYMatrix)`.
My understanding is that when rotation around Y is first applied, it sets a new frame, as shown in figure 2. After that, moving by -1 unit along Z should have been happened along new Z, as shown in image 3. This means that the object should orbit and not spin. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Why would it set a new frame? After the multiplication with the rotation matrix, the positions are rotated, but these simply still are 3D positions - which are then translated. Perhaps the confusion comes from doing multiple rotations around different axes, where the results can differ depending on the order of the axes (also see "gimbal lock")?

Comment: so, if this doesn't change the frame, why when we do translate (T) first and then rotate (R) it orbits? When it translates wouldn't it be at the same location where it would have been if we did R first and then T? If yes, so what's the difference? After it translates it will rotate just like when it did R first and then T around axis Y.

Comment: Rotation always happens around the origin (0,0,0). The object is defined in such a way that the y-axis is in the middle of the object, so when rotation is applied first, it looks like the object is spinning. When translation is applied first, the y-axis is no longer in the middle of the object, so it looks like the object is orbiting around the y-axis. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: `MathHelper::matrixMul4x4(M, transMatrix, rotYMatrix)` first rotates and than translates. You have to read it from the right to the left. Also see [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations):

Comment: Note that in the example in the video, the object is translated along the y-axis and rotated around the y-axis (the y-axis will be in the center of the object after either transformation), so in this case the results are the same for rotating first and translating first.

Comment: @Yun, isn't it translated along z-axis? The `TransMatrix` is set to `(0,0,-1)`

Comment: Yes, but that's the view (V) which is applied _after_ T-then-R or R-then-T in any case. You could see R-then-T as rotating an object in place, then placing it into a world, and finally controlling its position relative to the camera with V.

Comment: (The object is both translated to -1 on the z-axis for the View, and is translated along the y-axis to move it up in the world.)

Comment: the shader does `mP*mV*mM*vPosition`. `mM` matrix transforms the vertices of the Model from its local coordinates to world coordinates, right? And then applying `mV` which transforms to camera coordinates, right? The line 156 applies `transMatrix` which is `(0,0,-1)` on `M`. So, can you please explain what do you mean by "after"? It's applied on M before applying V. Or, Did I misunderstand all this?

Comment: Applying a transformation always operates in reference to the world basis axes. A rotation will effectively rotate an object around it's origin with angles that are expressed relative to the world axis angles. A translation will take that object and put in a specific location, with the distances expressed as scalars of the world-axis unit vectors, i.e. the world axes are not rotated! If you would invert the order, the same things happen, but the difference is that the object is not around it's origin when the rotation kicks in, and so the object starts flying through space instead of spinning.

Comment: @theateist Apologies, I had `mV` and `mM` mixed up. Indeed, the object is indeed first rotated in place (spinning), then translated to (0, 0, -1) and finally moved up by 1 unit by `V`. In the example, applying the translation to (0, 0, -1) first and then rotating would produce a different result (i.e. an orbiting object).